# What is the clear difference between "easy" and "simple"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

How can I undestand which of the two words I should use in sentences like that: "It is not necessarily easy to think in a new language (especially if you’ve never done it before) but it is still simple – there is no magic here".

Comment: What did you find when you looked these words up in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the fact that the words are often used interchangeably, there is a difference.

**Easy** is ultimately a subjective experiential predicate.  You think it is easy (for you) to do something.   You experience no difficulty. Walking is easy for an adult. Walking is not easy for a toddler.

**Simple** is an objective predicate.  Something is objectively simple or complex, based on an external definition of simplicity.  Water is a simple molecule. Methyl-ethyl-ketone-peroxide is a more complex molecule.